# Background Image not displaying on child element when parent already has background image

Tags: html, css

This is a sample code to show you what i want to do. I have a background image on body and a background image on h1 but the background image on h1 isn't rendering!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background: url("https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page169/art-school/images/bg.jpg") center 0 no-repeat;
      }
      h1 {
        background-image: url("https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page169/art-school/images/block-1-shadow.png");
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image in `h1` is here, it is just that basicaly, it is pretty much transparent.

I made 2 demo, in the first I added the line below and you can see the grey shadow from it which is your image.

```css
background-position: center;
```

In Demo 2, I add the background image in a pseudo-element `:after` to add a background behind the image and show it better.

### DEMO 1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background: url("https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page169/art-school/images/bg.jpg") center 0 no-repeat;
      }
      h1{
        background-image: url("https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page169/art-school/images/block-1-shadow.png");
        background-position: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

### DEMO 2

```css
h1{
  background:cornsilk;
  position:relative;
}
h1:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url("https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page169/art-school/images/block-1-shadow.png");
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background: url("https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page169/art-school/images/bg.jpg") center 0 no-repeat;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```